# Heroku: Not Found & Process Exited

Tags: ruby, deployment, heroku, sinatra, thin

I'm not sure how I can debug this. Running this ruby/sinatra/thin app locally I have no issues whatsoever. On Heroku however the app doesn't seem to load, says "Not Found.". I'm not sure how to make sense of the logs:

```
2013-03-20T22:27:41+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:27:41+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:28:04+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/ host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-03-20T22:28:05+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-03-20T22:28:05+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info code= desc="Blank app" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno= queue= wait= connect= service= status=502 bytes=
2013-03-20T22:37:08+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-20T22:37:59+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:37:59+00:00 heroku[api]: Add  config by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:37:59+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:38:00+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:38:00+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 0a18d12 by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:38:00+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 33969`
2013-03-20T22:38:00+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-20T22:38:01+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found
2013-03-20T22:38:02+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-03-20T22:38:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-20T22:38:19+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=3ms service=79ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:38:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=13ms connect=12ms service=69ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:38:21+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=21ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:50:19+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-20T22:51:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:51:01+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy e18aad6 by mymail@gmail.com
2013-03-20T22:51:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-03-20T22:51:02+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-20T22:51:09+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-20T22:52:32+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=6ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:52:33+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:52:33+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=1ms connect=4ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:52:34+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=4ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:52:35+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=12ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=18
2013-03-20T22:52:35+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=ancient-kings-2615.herokuapp.com fwd="92.225.106.224" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=2ms connect=5ms service=4ms status=404 bytes=18
```

Any ideas?

**Update 21.3.2013**

my gemfile

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

# Sinatra
gem "rake"
gem "thin"
gem "sinatra", "~> 1.3.4"
gem "sinatra-contrib", "~> 1.3.1"
gem 'sinatra-assetpack', :require => 'sinatra/assetpack'

# Sass
gem "sass", "~> 3.2.1"

# Mailing related
gem "hominid", "~> 3.0.5"

# Google Analytics: UNCOMMENT IF DESIRED, THEN ADD YOUR OWN ACCOUNT INFO TO config.ru
#gem 'rack-google-analytics', "~> 0.9.2"
```

my config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require './app.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Comment: This line appears to be the start of the problem: "2013-03-20T22:38:01+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bundle: command not found". Could you post your Gemfile and how you've called Bundler in the app to set up the requires? Oh, and some versions of things - Sinatra, Ruby, Bundler.

Comment: Hey @iain, rails 3.2.12, bundler 1.1.5. I've used this project as a starter here: https://github.com/jasonmelgoza/armor

Comment: What's this line at the top of `app.rb` for? `$:.unshift File.expand_path('../../../lib', __FILE__)` I don't see a `lib` directory!

Comment: Uh, I'm not sure what exactly it does I checked my file structure and now there is a v folder that definitely wasn't there before @iain. It contains folders like admin/app/config/lib/log/public/script/test. I also downloaded a fresh armor install and deployed to Heroku basically giving me the same "Not found" error.

Comment: @iain forget about that v directory, I have no idea on Earth how it got there, but it certainly has no business being there.

Comment: Sometimes it's a good idea to delete the Heroku app and start again. I've had that, it could be at there end. Definitely remove that line though, it's not useful.

Comment: Cheers @iain. Here's the thing, I thought I had borked something but it looks like it's actually a problem somewhere since the app throws that error with every fresh install. Some of his changes must have brought about the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cloned the repo but couldn't get it to work via `rackup`, which is what Heroku relies up to run an app. It did work when running the Sinatra app directly via Ruby. Here are the changes I made that got it to work with `rackup`:

#### config.ru

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.require

require File.expand_path 'app.rb', File.dirname(__FILE__)
run App
```

[If you've subclassed, run the subclass, otherwise use Sinatra::Application](http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#heroku)

I also removed **all** the `$:.unshifts` that I found, as they're evil.

Comment: <3<3<3. How's that they're evil, what was its purpose?